# How do you move a heading 50px from another heading?

Tags: css, html, position

I know you can make lets say a header 50 pixels from the left. But can you make something 50 pixels from ANOTHER heading? Not just from the margin? Like heading 2 needs to be 50 pixels from heading 1. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

make them both inline-block and add 50px margin-right on the first one.

```
<style>h1, h2 { display: inline-block; margin-right: 50px; }</style>
<h1>my thing</h1>
<h2>my other thing<h2>
```

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/bpR7H/

**Note:** You need to avoid `position: absolute` for this to work properly, because absolutely positioned elements don't affect the position of other elements.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/w9FHw/

Something like that?

```
#rightheading {
    position: relative;
    left: 50px
}
```